# Return all rows with redundant where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

when i joined two table and added following where , not all rows are returned, if remove this where much more will return , why?

```
where [DeliveryAttribute].RainbowLevel = [DeliveryAttribute].RainbowLevel
```

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: You've just discovered another (obscure) way to write `where [DeliveryAttribute].RainbowLevel IS NOT NULL` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of:

```
x = x
```

Is `unknown` if `x` is `null`.  In that case, those rows will be filtered out by the `where` clause.

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88120/1/0)

Comment: really? and what when x can be null?